# Подпись к элементам слайдера

Tags: javascript, html, css

Доброго времени суток!
Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать подпись к элементу слайдера?

Подключён `Owl-carousel 2`

```
<div id="services-slide" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    ...
    <div class="owl-item">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images1.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images2.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

соответственно слайдов может быть сколько угодно.
Как сделать так, что бы справа снизу была текстовая подпись,например

```
"Слайдер1",
"Слайдер2" и т.д.
```

Я планировал сделать без [js](/questions/tagged/js) вроде этого,
для `owl-item` сделать:

```
#services-slide .owl-item:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

a уже в `content:"";` добавлять текст в зависимости от выбранного слайда.
Подскажите, возможно ли это? если да поделитесь пожалуйста идеей)
Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так

```css
#services-slide {
    counter-reset: section;
}

#services-slide .owl-item {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #555555;
}

#services-slide .owl-item:after {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: "Слайдер " counters(section, "");
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="services-slide" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="owl-item">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images1.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="owl-item">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images2.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```